# how can I call bean method on button click in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces, javabeans, commandbutton

I have a jsf component with action

```
<h:form>
   <a4j:commandButton value="click" action="#{myBean.method()}" />
</h:form>
```

the problem is that bean's method "method" was called only once at first click,
how can I fix it that it will be called at every click on

Comment: Post more of the surrounding markup. Do you have another `<h:form/>` enclosing the one you've shown here? What version of JSF/Richfaces are you running?

Comment: I don't have another <h:form> tag, I am using JSF 2.2 and Richfaces 4

Comment: Press F12 in browser for clues.

Comment: Problem is not in `a4j:commandButton` code. You can add `oncomplete` attribute (with alert) there and temporary remove action attribute for testing purpose. And if it regular submit button without ajax, then you can use `h:commandButton`.